# Create new module in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: module, prestashop

I'm new to Prestashop. I have a newbie question...

I'm making a module and everything is working, but I'm thinking that I can do it better.
The way I understand that a new module is created is:

```
/modules/your_module/your_module.php
/modules/your_module/your_module.tpl
```

Then you can override the "tpl" file on your own theme:

```
/themes/your_theme/modules/your_module.tpl
```

ok, at this point everything works, but the problem I see is that I have to dirty the base prestashop installation.

1) Can I make a module in my theme folder without make a module in /modules folder?

I want to develop a theme in a local environment and then upload a package to my production server.

I've read the documentation, but I don't understand if this is the only way to make a theme or there is a better way to encapsulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the module in `modules` because PrestaShop loads modules from that directory. You can't put it in `themes/modules` because that is only for overriding module TPL, CSS and JS files.

Don't worry, you won't pollute the PrestaShop core. You can put custom modules in the `modules` directory jut like you put a custom theme in `themes`.

You can develop your module locally then you can upload it to your production server.